# locker puzzle using a boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, puzzle

I don't want the answer I want to know what I a doing wrong. below is the question

A school has 100 lockers and 100 students. All lockers are closed on the first day of school. As the students enter, the first student, denoted S1, opens every locker. Then the second student, S2, begins with the second locker, denoted L2, and closes every other locker. Student S3 begins with the third locker and changes every third locker (closes it if it was open, and opens it if it was closed). Student S4 begins with locker L4 and changes every fourth locker. Student S5 starts with L5 and changes every fifth locker, and so on until student S100 changes L100.

After all the students have passed through the building and changed the lockers, which lockers are open? Write a program to find your answer. The program should display the answer

and my code is

```
public class LockerPuzzle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        
        boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];

        // first all the lockers are closed. false represents closed
        for (int i= 0; i<lockers.length;i++){
            lockers[i]= false;
            System.out.println(lockers[i]);
        }

        // then the first student comme and opens all the lockers
        for (int i = 0; i< lockers.length; i++){
           lockers[i] = true;
        }

       
        int locker = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j<= lockers.length; j++){
            for(int k =j; k< lockers.length; k =k+j){
                if(lockers[k] == false){
                    lockers[k]=true;
                }else{
                    lockers[k]= true;
                }

            }
        }

        // this prints all the open lockers.
        for(int S=0; S<lockers.length; S++)
        {
            if (lockers[S] == true) {
                System.out.println("Locker " + S + " Open");
            }

    }
  }
}
```

and the output for me is saying all lockers are open.

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: You should always start with `int k = j - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this block:

```
if(lockers[k] == false){
    lockers[k]=true;
}else{
    lockers[k]= true;
}
```

which will set lockers[k] to true either way. You can avoid this sort of typo by just replacing it with `lockers[k] = !lockers[k]`.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412112/locker-puzzle-using-a-boolean-array#comment117408817_66412112l), I still think you would benefit from some general tips and directions that will reduce your code size.

As @onkarruikar noted, you don't have to manually initialise your `lockers` table. `new boolean[100]` creates an array with all elements set to `false`.

As @MathiasRaba has mentioned, you don't need an if/else block to open/close a locker. Simply set the locker to its opposite value.

Now lets consider the actual simulation of locking and unlocking. `i`-th student begins with the `i`-th locker and then proceeds on to a locker that is `i + 1` elements away. Something like this:

```
boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < 100; j += i + 1) {
        lockers[j] = !lockers[j];
    }
}
```

Note that the numbering of students/lockers is zero based in order to play better with array indices.

Comment: Thank you but can you please explain why we should add 1 to me, please

Comment: First, I've re-inxed students and locks from: `S1-S100, L1-L100` to `S0-S99,L0-L99`. Note that the outer loop starts with `i=0`. If I want the inner loop to advance, I can't do: `j+=0`. So I add 1 to account for that and everything works.

Comment: @vardhanPatel Note that this way you no longer need any manual initilization loop outside of this loop. No need for the initial true / false setting, the default of false / closed for every locker is correct and this loop now covers all the students coming in, including the very first one that switches every locker from closed to open.

Answer (score 0):

No need to start with 1. Zero indexing is good to go.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        boolean LockerList [] = new boolean [100];
        
        for (int s=0; s<100; s++)                 // student loop [0..99]
            for (int l=s; l<100; l=l+(s+1))       // locker loop  [0..99]
                LockerList[l] = !LockerList[l];   // toggle value

        // display open-lockers
        for (int x=0; x<100; x++)
            if (LockerList[x] == true)
                System.out.printf("Locker %d is open\n", x+1);
    }
}

// hints: s=5 is the 6th student so he will hop six boxes i.e. s+1
//        And do not display last locker as 99, it should be 100 i.e. x+1
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion, you do not have to write following code.

```
// first all the lockers are closed. false represents closed
for (int i= 0; i<lockers.length;i++){
     lockers[i]= false;
     System.out.println(lockers[i]);
}
```

Array elements are automatically initialized to defaults. 
In case of boolean the default value is `false`

Comment: while true this does not answer the question in any way.

Comment: The author has asked  `I want to know what I a doing wrong.` So giving him the suggestion.

Comment: But this is not *wrong*, it is inefficient and not needed but it is not wrong.